# Why can't I insert into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, geospatial, spatial, mysql-error-1416

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(11) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| utm     | point   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

insert into life(user_id, utm)  values(99,point(4,4));

ERROR 1416 (22003): Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
insert into life(user_id, utm)  values(99,PointFromWKB(POINT(4,4)));
```

Comment: According to http://bit.ly/9r97o5, this is only required on MySQL versions prior to 5.1.35. Starting with 5.1.35, you can insert the return value from Point() directly.

Comment: Are function names case sensitive in mySQL?