# Why can't I do this INSERT in MYSQL? (Python MySQLdb)

Tags: python, mysql, database, insert

This is a follow up to this question I asked earlier:
[Why can't I insert into MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267034/why-cant-i-insert-into-mysql/2267076#2267076)

That question solved it partly. Now I'm doing it in Python and it's not working :(

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO life(user_id, utm)  values(%s,PointFromWKB(point(%s,%s)))",the_user_id, utm_easting, utm_northing)
```

I even did float(utm_easting) and float(utm_northing)

Edit: this is the error:

**execute() takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)**

Comment: What error messages do you get? WHat does the final query look like?

Comment: I don't know....how do I print that out from cursor? cursor.last_query or something?

Comment: I don't know (I don't know anything about Python) but usually it's something along the lines of last_query or executed_query. The error message might be more enlightening, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here (pdf)](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.pdf):

> Following the statement string
>   argument to execute(), **provide a tuple**
>   containing the values to be bound to
>   the placeholders, in the order they
>   should appear within the string. If
>   you have only a single value x,
>   specify it as (x,) to indicate a
>   single-element tuple.

tl;dr:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO life(user_id, utm) 
    values(%s,PointFromWKB(point(%s,%s)))""", 
    (the_user_id, utm_easting, utm_northing))
```

Edit:  you can alternatively pass a list as `execute()`'s second argument.

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO life(user_id, utm) 
    values(%s,PointFromWKB(point(%s,%s)))""", 
    [the_user_id, utm_easting, utm_northing])
```

Answer (score 1):

This could depend on whatever API you use for SQL calls, but it could be that either:

a) values are in fact not strings and you need to replace %s with appropriate types (%d for integers, for example?), or

b) string values need to be quoted like this: `values('%s',PointFromWKB(point('%s','%s')))`

Comment: @Gnudiff:  `%s` is the parameter marker used by MySQLdb for any value being passed to the query.  You do not need to quote any values; even strings.  See here for details:  http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Put parantheses around my variables.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO life(user_id, utm)  values(%s,PointFromWKB(point(%s,%s)))",(the_user_id, utm_easting, utm_northing))
```